# apalike-derivative bibliography style file doesn't lowercase titles

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using a .bst bibliography style file that apparently is a derivative of the apalike.bst style. As I have learned, it is supposed to typeset the titles of all references in a lowercase manner (except for those parts put in curly brackets, of course).

Funny thing is: This is not happening, i.e. the titles appear as put into the .bib file.

This seems to be the responsible code snippet:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
%    { title "t" change.case$ }
    { title }
  if$
}
```

Of course, I have already tried to uncomment the line with the change.case command. This, however, only gave me plenty of error messages following this style:

```
while executing---line 1376 of file apalike-derivative.bst
`'62' is a function literal, not an integer, for entry Zhu2017
while executing---line 1376 of file apalike-derivative.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string or missing field, for entry Zhu2017
```

With the respective line commented, no error messages occur, but, as mentioned, the titles are not set in lowercase letters.

How can I make this right, i.e. keep this style file, but apply the proper adaptions to get the titles set in a lowercase manner?

Comment: You do not only have to uncomment the `{ title "t" change.case$ }` line you also have to comment out the following `{ title }` line. You can only have two `{ ... }` groups in an `if$` after the condition (`title empty$`).

Comment: Would you care to post this as an answer? Because this was exactly the solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment the `{ title "t" change.case$ }`, but you also need to comment out the `{ title }` so that the code reads

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
%   { title }
  if$
}
```

or simplified without comments

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

The syntax of a conditional in the BibTeX language is

```
<condition>
  { <true branch> }
  { <false branch> }
if$
```

If you have three braced groups between the condition and the `if$`, BibTeX gets confused.